# Passing args from a batch file to a C# program with a space

Tags: c#, batch-file

I'm trying to pass **arguments/parameters** from a batch file to a simple **C#** *Console.Writeline(args[0])* program.

My program's exe file has a **two-word name with a space** and that's the problem! The whole thing only works when I **rename the exe file to a whole word** and write `start SchoolBook.exe OMG` and the arg[0] then becomes equal to "OMG".
But in any other case the program won't start.

- If I leave it *start School Book.exe OMG* it says **"Windows cannot find "School".. "**
- If I put double quotes: `start "School Book.exe" OMG` it says **"Windows cannot find "OMG".. "**
- If I put single quotes it can't find **"School"**
- I tried putting a '-' before the OMG, putting quotes around the OMG, even putting `%1%` before it NO! Nothing works..
  Any help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'll do the same thing, you made me curious hang on :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created an empty command application "School Book" which when built produces the executable `School Book.exe`.

My pretty empty implementation:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(args[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

In my command box I can execute the program like this:

```
Debug>start "" "School Book.exe" OMG
```

Now a messagebox pops up with "OMG"

Comment: Yes! Changing ( start "School Book.exe" OMG ) to ( start "" "School Book.exe" OMG ) in the batch file does the trick. Thank you @Haxx

Comment: No probs, glad that i could help :). hf coding :)